# What causes and how can I remove an empty space between content and scroll in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, adaptive-design

Please help me to understand what is the space between content and scroll?!
When I look at the developer inspector I can see that the width of my content is 419px and at the top I can see that 419px. So everything is going to be alright... [image] But what the hell... why do I have the empty space between my content and scroll, somebody please explain me.

I learned to layout websites as shown in the video and did everything exactly as in the videos (guy in the video uses Safari and he has got a mac). I have cloned his job, his code and everything and I don't know why I have this space...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.